# How to display two different return values from if/elif in Python?

Tags: python

I'm reading a csv file and appending the data into a list and later using another function, I'm calculating these numbers and try to return two values using if/elif statements. To display the result I have created a procedure called displayData(numbers) and here I'm struggling to show the calculated values from previous function called seyrogus(numbers) against the original csv values.
Currently, it's showing all only "4" as result. Where I'm doing wrong?

**My code so far**

```
def getData():

  numbers = []

  file = open("numbers.csv","r")

  for line in file:

    data = line.strip()

    numbers.append(int(data.strip()))
  
  return numbers


def seyrogus(numbers):

  for counter in range(len(numbers)):
    if numbers[counter] % 2 != 0:
      return (int(numbers[counter] * 3) + 1)

    elif numbers[counter] % 2 == 0:
      return (int(numbers[counter] / 2))

def displayData(numbers):

  print("Original Numbers \t Converted Numbers")

  for counter in range(len(numbers)):

    print(f"{numbers[counter]} \t \t \t {seyrogus(numbers)}")
  
def main():

  numbers = getData()
  displayData(numbers)
 

main()
```

**output**

```
Original Numbers         Converted Numbers
1                        4
2                        4
3                        4
4                        4
5                        4
6                        4
7                        4
8                        4
9                        4
10                       4
11                       4
12                       4
13                       4
14                       4
15                       4
16                       4
17                       4
18                       4
19                       4
20                       4
21                       4
22                       4
23                       4
24                       4
25                       4
26                       4
27                       4
28                       4
29                       4
30                       4
31                       4
32                       4
33                       4
34                       4
35                       4
36                       4
37                       4
38                       4
39                       4
40                       4
41                       4
42                       4
43                       4
44                       4
45                       4
46                       4
47                       4
48                       4
49                       4
50                       4
51                       4
52                       4
53                       4
54                       4
55                       4
56                       4
57                       4
58                       4
59                       4
60                       4
61                       4
62                       4
63                       4
64                       4
65                       4
66                       4
67                       4
68                       4
69                       4
70                       4
71                       4
72                       4
73                       4
74                       4
75                       4
76                       4
77                       4
78                       4
79                       4
80                       4
81                       4
82                       4
83                       4
84                       4
85                       4
86                       4
87                       4
88                       4
89                       4
90                       4
91                       4
92                       4
93                       4
94                       4
95                       4
96                       4
97                       4
98                       4
99                       4
100                      4
```

**csv file**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `seyrogus` function needs to return a list rather than returning a single value.  The reason you're only getting `4` as the result is that every time you call it, it iterates over `numbers` from the beginning and then returns the first converted value rather than iterating over the entire list.

Both `getData` and `seyrogus` can be implemented very simply as list comprehensions.  You then need to iterate over both `numbers` and `seyrogus(numbers)` in parallel in `displayData`; an easy way of doing that is the `zip` function.

```
def getData():
    with open("numbers.csv") as file:
        return [int(line.strip()) for line in file]

def seyrogus(numbers):
    return [n * 3 + 1 if n % 2 else n // 2 for n in numbers]

def displayData(numbers):
    print("Original Numbers \t Converted Numbers")
    for original, converted in zip(numbers, seyrogus(numbers)):
        print(f"{original} \t \t \t {converted}")

def main():
    displayData(getData())

main()
```

prints:

```
Original Numbers         Converted Numbers
1                        4
2                        1
3                        10
4                        2
5                        16
6                        3
7                        22
8                        4
9                        28
10                       5
11                       34
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks. Can we further add a calculation on even and odd numbers, let's say if even it became half and if odd it should multiply by 3 and add 1 to it? e.g. currently 3 became 10  so 10 half will be 5 which is odd (5*3)+1 = 16 half again 8 half again 4 half again 2 half again 1....

Comment: "if even if became half and if odd it should multiply by 3 and add 1" is exactly what the code already does.